# nginxproxy/nginx-proxy not resolving VIRTUAL_HOST as expected

Tags: nginx, docker

I would like to use a reverse proxy with this docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - hello-world
      
      
  hello-world:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: hello.world
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

What I expect to happen is that `curl -H "Host: hello.world" localhost:80` would return the index.html in the folder *web*. But actually it is return the "Welcome to nginx!" page so it seems it does not resolve the VIRTUAL_HOST at all.

What actually works as expected is the following call: `curl -H "Host: hello.world" localhost:9001` which return the index.html as expected. But why cannot it resolve the hostname?. Eventually this is a very minimal example of my setup.

It is running on an arm64 machine with docker version: *Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c28948e*.

What fundamental mistake am I doing here? I tried to implement it as described on [README of the nginx-proxy project](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy).

**EDIT**:

When I start with `docker-compose up -d` and then run `docker-compose ps` I get:

```
               Name                              Command               State                  Ports                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
minimal-proxy-example_hello-world_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9001->80/tcp,:::9001->80/tcp
minimal-proxy-example_nginx-proxy_1   /app/docker-entrypoint.sh  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
```

I am running docker on Arch Linux on a [Raspberry Pi 4 using a AArch64 kernel](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-4). I tried the same on a normal Amd64 PC with the same result. However I tried also the very same with docker-desktop on Windows 10. I used a [git-bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) to be able to use *curl*. And there it all worked as expected! **Why does this work on docker-desktop on Windows 10 but not on Arch Linux?** As consequence I also posted this question in the [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265751).

**Update**

I think the problem relates to this bug: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/1548